# Yank multiple lines without using visual mode

Tags: cut-copy-paste, multiple-lines

I have the text:

```
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
```

my cursor is in the first line, and I want to yank the first 2 lines.

Usually I would do it by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, selecting the second line by going down with <kbd>j</kbd> and yanking with <kbd>y</kbd>.

How can this be achieved without using visual mode?

Comment: [How can I yank multiple lines into a register?](https://superuser.com/q/234317)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! 

Comment: Using `2yy` also works.

Comment: `2yy`, `2Y`, `yj`, `y<enter>`

Comment: @Quasímodo too bad that’s not on [vi.se], otherwise it would make a great dupe target.

Comment: @filbranden Welcome to Stack Exchange! You must be new here! Please do not answer questions in the comment section, and refrain from using it for social chit-chat.

Answer (score 4):

`y`ank is an *operator* like `d` and `c`, which means it works on all *motions* and *text-objects* (see the relevant help sections).

That means that `yip`, `y)`, `ygg`, `yib`, `y/pattern<CR>`, `yfc` etc., all work (and with registers, too)! They can potentially be multiple lines.

In this case I would probably use `yj` (and *not* `y2j`) because yank will include the current line and the one we land on.

Note that some motions are not line-wise by default. You can use `yV{motion}` to force a line-wise yank.

Comment: What's the difference between a *motion* and a *text-object* - will you give an example? I would consider `w`, `W`, `e`, etc. all motions, since they move the cursor.

Comment: @Shuzheng that’s correct. Motions move the cursor. Text objects are a bit harder to explain ; they’re like « targets »—you can select them in visual mode or operate on them with operators. See the help on text objects for more. There are a couple examples in the answer

Comment: So, would `ib`, `ip`, and `a"` be considered text objects? I've seen these in `:h text-objects`. I use these often with the `d` (delete) operator.

Comment: @Shuzheng yes, those are text objects. y,c,g~, etc all work with them too (not just d!)